# First sheaf cohomology $H^1(\mathscr{O}_D, \mathbb{D})=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology

Can I get a hint on this problem?

Given a finite divisor $D=p_1+\dots +p_m -q_1 -\dots -q_n$ on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, how do I show that the first sheaf cohomology group $H^1(\mathscr{O}_D, \mathbb{D})=0$?

I was first only considering effective divisors, which would make $\mathscr{O}_D$ a subset of the holomorphic functions. We can also pick a covering $(U_i)$ such that each $p$ is only contained in a single open set $U$. Then I could split any cochain $(f_{ij})$ into $g_j-g_i$ of holomorphic functions. Then I want to somehow get the functions $g_i$ to be zero at the necessary points, maybe by multiplying $g_i$ by $(z-p_i)$ locally in $U_i$. But this doesn't seem to be likely to work.

My motivation for doing this is to show that on any compact riemann surface X, a covering $(U_i)$ where all the $U_i$ are isomorphic to disks is a leray covering relative to any sheaf of a divisor $\mathscr{O}_D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a simple example. Namely, let's show that $\mathcal{O}(-p)$ (for some point $p$) has vanishing cohomology.

Begin by considering that we have the following short exact sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}(-p)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}\to i_\ast\mathcal{O}_p\to 0$$

where $i$ is the inclusion of the point $p$ into $\mathbb{D}$ (and $\mathcal{O}_p$ is the structure sheaf on the point). Then, we get the LES

$$0\to \mathcal{O}(-p)(\mathbb{D})\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(\mathbb{D})\to \mathbb{C}\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}(-p))\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}})$$

But, note that using the exponential sequence

$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}\to\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}^\times\to 0$$

we have the long exact sequence

$$0\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(\mathbb{D})\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(\mathbb{D})^\times\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}})\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}^\times)\to H^2(\mathbb{D},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$$

But, since $\mathbb{D}$ is contractible

$$H^1(\mathbb{D},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})=H^2(\mathbb{D},\underline{\mathbb{Z}})=0$$

and so

$$H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}})=H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}^\times)=\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{D})$$

But, $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{D})=\mathrm{Cl}(\mathbb{D})=0$. The last equality follows by the Mittag-Leffler theorem.

Thus, from this side computation we see that we have the exact sequence

$$0\to\mathcal{O}(-p)(\mathbb{D})\to\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{D})\to\mathbb{C}\to H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}(-p))\to 0$$

and thus proving that $H^1(\mathbb{D},\mathcal{O}(-p))=0$ is equivalent to showing that

$$0\to \mathcal{O}(-p)(\mathbb{D})\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{D}}(\mathbb{D})\to \mathbb{C}\to 0$$

is exact.

Do you see how to do this? Do you see how to generalize this?

Comment: Just curious, but doesn't the Mittag-Leffler theorem just state that $H^1(\mathbb{D}, \mathcal{O}) = 0$? Why are the Picard and class groups involved?

Comment: @msteve I mean, to me, the Mittag-Leffler theorem says that any divisor is principal. In other words, that the class group is trivial. This is the usual statement I know in terms of having a discrete set of points with integers, and finding a function whose poles/zeros have those orders.

Comment: Fair enough - I'd only ever seen it stated as $H^1(\mathcal{O}) = 0$ (as in e.g. Kaup & Kaup), but they are definitely equivalent. Thanks!